# Android - Add Margin for SpannableStringBuilder using ReplacementSpan

Tags: android, hashtag, spannablestring, android-chips

I'm trying to format Hashtags inside a TextView/EditText (Say like Chips mentioned in the Material Design Specs). I'm able to format the background using `ReplacementSpan`. But the problem is that I'm not able to increase the line spacing in the TextView/EditText. See the image below
[image]

The question is how do I add top and bottom margin for the hashtags?

Here is the code where I add the background to the text:

```
   /**
     * First draw a rectangle
     * Then draw text on top
     */
    @Override
    public void draw(Canvas canvas, CharSequence text, int start, int end, float x, int top, int y, int bottom, Paint paint) {
        RectF rect = new RectF(x, top, x + measureText(paint, text, start, end), bottom);
        paint.setColor(backgroundColor);
        canvas.drawRoundRect(rect, CORNER_RADIUS, CORNER_RADIUS, paint);
        paint.setColor(textColor);
        canvas.drawText(text, start, end, x, y, paint);
    }
```

Comment: So did it end up working for you?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I had a similar problem a while ago and this is the solution I've come up with:

The hosting TextView in xml:

```
<TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="18dp"
        android:paddingBottom="18dp"
        android:paddingLeft="8dp"
        android:paddingRight="8dp"
        android:gravity="fill"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:lineSpacingExtra="10sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:text="@{viewModel.renderedTagBadges}">
```

A custom version of `ReplacementSpan`

```
public class TagBadgeSpannable extends ReplacementSpan implements LineHeightSpan {

    private static int CORNER_RADIUS = 30;
    private final int textColor;
    private final int backgroundColor;
    private final int lineHeight;

    public TagBadgeSpannable(int lineHeight, int textColor, int backgroundColor) {
        super();
        this.textColor = textColor;
        this.backgroundColor = backgroundColor;
        this.lineHeight = lineHeight;
    }

    @Override
    public void draw(Canvas canvas, CharSequence text, int start, int end, float x, int top, int y, int bottom, Paint paint) {
        final float textSize = paint.getTextSize();
        final float textLength = x + measureText(paint, text, start, end);
        final float badgeHeight = textSize * 2.25f;
        final float textOffsetVertical = textSize * 1.45f;

        RectF badge = new RectF(x, y, textLength, y + badgeHeight);
        paint.setColor(backgroundColor);
        canvas.drawRoundRect(badge, CORNER_RADIUS, CORNER_RADIUS, paint);

        paint.setColor(textColor);
        canvas.drawText(text, start, end, x, y + textOffsetVertical, paint);
    }

    @Override
    public int getSize(Paint paint, CharSequence text, int start, int end, Paint.FontMetricsInt fm) {
        return Math.round(paint.measureText(text, start, end));
    }

    private float measureText(Paint paint, CharSequence text, int start, int end) {
        return paint.measureText(text, start, end);
    }

    @Override
    public void chooseHeight(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2, int i3, Paint.FontMetricsInt fontMetricsInt) {
        fontMetricsInt.bottom += lineHeight;
        fontMetricsInt.descent += lineHeight;
    }
}
```

And finally a builder that creates the Spannable

```
public class AndroidTagBadgeBuilder implements TagBadgeBuilder {

    private final SpannableStringBuilder stringBuilder;
    private final String textColor;
    private final int lineHeight;

    public AndroidTagBadgeBuilder(SpannableStringBuilder stringBuilder, int lineHeight, String textColor) {
        this.stringBuilder = stringBuilder;
        this.lineHeight = lineHeight;
        this.textColor = textColor;
    }

    @Override
    public void appendTag(String tagName, String badgeColor) {
        final String nbspSpacing = "\u202F\u202F"; // none-breaking spaces

        String badgeText = nbspSpacing + tagName + nbspSpacing;
        stringBuilder.append(badgeText);
        stringBuilder.setSpan(
            new TagBadgeSpannable(lineHeight, Color.parseColor(textColor), Color.parseColor(badgeColor)),
            stringBuilder.length() - badgeText.length(),
            stringBuilder.length()- badgeText.length() + badgeText.length(),
            Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE
        );
        stringBuilder.append("  ");
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getTags() {
        return stringBuilder;
    }

    @Override
    public void clear() {
        stringBuilder.clear();
        stringBuilder.clearSpans();
    }
}
```

The outcome will look something like this:
[image: Rendered badges in TextView]

Tweak the measures in `TagBadgeSpannable` to your liking.

I've uploaded a very minimal sample project using this code to [github](https://github.com/danielw93/spannable-badge-example) so feel free to check it out.

**NOTE:** The sample uses Android Databinding and is written MVVM style

Comment: For anyone following this solution you may have some very ODD looking chips. This seems to make this code much more "in-line" see these lines in the onDraw method.





`RectF badge = new RectF(x, y, textLength, y + badgeHeight);`
`///.....`
`canvas.drawText(text, start, end, x, y + textOffsetVertical, paint);`

Answer (score 8):

Text markup in Android is so poorly documented, writing this code is like feeling your way through the dark.

I've done a little bit of it, so I will share what I know.

You can handle line spacing by wrapping your chip spans inside a `LineHeightSpan`.  `LineHeightSpan` is an interface that extends the `ParagraphStyle` marker interface, so this tells you it affects appearance at a paragraph level.  Maybe a good way to explain it is to compare your `ReplacementSpan` subclass to an HTML `<span>`, whereas a `ParagraphStyle` span like `LineHeightSpan` is like an HTML `<div>`.

The `LineHeightSpan` interface consists of one method:

```
public void chooseHeight(CharSequence text, int start, int end,
                         int spanstartv, int v,
                         Paint.FontMetricsInt fm);
```

This method is called for each line in your paragraph

- `text` is your `Spanned` string.
- `start` is the index of the character at the start of the current line
- `end` is the index of the character at the end of the current line
- `spanstartv` is (IIRC) the vertical offset of the entire span itself
- `v` is (IIRC) the vertical offset of the current line
- `fm` is the `FontMetrics` object, which is actually a returned (in/out) parameter.  Your code will make changes to `fm` and `TextView` will use those when drawing.

So what the `TextView` will do is call this method once for every line it processes.  Based on the parameters, along with your `Spanned` string, you set up the `FontMetrics` to render the line with the values of your choosing.

Here's an example I did for a bullet item in a list (think `<ol><li>`) where I wanted some separation between each list item:

```
    @Override
    public void chooseHeight(CharSequence text, int start, int end, int spanstartv, int v, Paint.FontMetricsInt fm) {

        int incr = Math.round(.36F * fm.ascent); // note: ascent is negative

        // first line: add space to the top
        if (((Spanned) text).getSpanStart(this) == start) {
            fm.ascent += incr;
            fm.top = fm.ascent + 1;
        }

        // last line: add space to the bottom
        if (((Spanned) text).getSpanEnd(this) == end) {
            fm.bottom -= incr;
        }

    }
```

Your version will probably be even simpler, just changing the `FontMetrics` the same way for each line that it's called.

When it comes to deciphering the `FontMetrics`, the logger and debugger are your friends.  You'll just have to keep tweaking values until you get something you like.

Answer (score 1):

Doesnt [BackgroundColorSpan](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/text/style/BackgroundColorSpan.java)  work?

For your specific case, you can also set the lineSpacing for the TextView.

One last option (didn't test this), would be to calculate the *height* of the span to be larger than the one that you are drawing. You can check getSize implementation in [DynamicDrawableSpan](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/text/style/DynamicDrawableSpan.java) to see how to set the height of the span using the given FontMetrics instance as a parameter.