# Spannable string not displayed when layout is vertical

Tags: java, android, textview, spannablestring

Recently a spannable string i was using in my application, stopped being displayed, on some devices.

It was working in the past, but then i'm not sure when it stopped working (probably after  recently updated the sdk).

Anyway what is happening is that the textView with the spannable is correctly displayed on some devices (i.e. tablet, or big screen devices, not all anyway, i.e. a one plus one is having this problem), but on other devices is not displayed at all (looks more not updated, since i tried to put a placeholder string, and this string is displayed even if i'm sure the setText method is being called).

So i'm not sure what can be the problem. This is the textView i'm using:

```
<TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:textSize="40dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:id="@+id/edition_name"
        android:shadowDx="3"
        android:shadowDy="3"
        android:shadowRadius="1.5"
        android:shadowColor="@color/transparentGrey"
        android:layout_below="@+id/space"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        />
```

And this is how i set the spannableString:

```
private void updateText(TextView textView, String title, String value){
        SpannableString styledString;

        if(title != null) {
            styledString = new SpannableString(title + ": " + value);
            styledString.setSpan(new StyleSpan(Typeface.BOLD), title.length() + 2, styledString.length(), Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
        } else {
            styledString = new SpannableString(value);
            styledString.setSpan(new StyleSpan(Typeface.BOLD), 0, styledString.length(), Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
        }
        Log.i(TAG, "Spannable String: " + styledString.toString());
        textView.setText(styledString);
        textView.invalidate();
    }
```

I'm in the else case. Anyway all the other spannable strings composed in the if part are working properly.

The spannable string i've checked is not empty.
And when in landscape mode it display the text. I thought tha can be related to a sizing issue, so i tried to make the string smalle, but without success.

Any idea of why it is happening?

I checked this question: [How come my spannable isn't shown?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47967798/how-come-my-spannable-isnt-shown/48058305)
Not sure if the case in the answer about the height applyo to my case. At the moment the height set for textView is wrap-content.

**--UPDATE**

Another interesting thing i found is that if i rotate the screen and it goes in landscape mode, the string appears (it use another layout file), and when i rotate it back to vertical position the string appears (not aligned anyway).

**Second Update**

Ok this is interesting, i tried to comment the use of spannable string, and use just the text as it is, i'm facing the same problem. 
Probably is wort showing the onActivityCreated method where i'm populating the components:

```
@Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        if(savedInstanceState != null){
            edition = (Edition) savedInstanceState.getSerializable(EDITION_DETAIL);
        }
        SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity());
        boolean useAppStorage = preferences.getBoolean("network_symbols", false);
        String imagePath;
        Activity currentActivity = getActivity();
        TextView editionCodeView =    (TextView) currentActivity.findViewById(R.id.edition_code);
        TextView editionLaunchView =  (TextView) currentActivity.findViewById(R.id.edition_launch);
        TextView editionNameView =    (TextView) currentActivity.findViewById(R.id.edition_name);
        TextView editionSizeView = (TextView) currentActivity.findViewById(R.id.edition_size);
        ImageView editionImageView = (ImageView) currentActivity.findViewById(R.id.edition_detail_image);
        TextView otherAttributes = (TextView) currentActivity.findViewById(R.id.otherAttributes);
        TextView cardsComposition = (TextView) currentActivity.findViewById(R.id.cards_composition);
        Button gathererButton = (Button) currentActivity.findViewById(R.id.gatherer_button);
        gathererButton.setOnClickListener(this);
        if(edition != null) {
            updateText(editionCodeView, currentActivity.getString(R.string.edition_code), edition.getCode());
            showLaunchText(editionLaunchView, currentActivity, edition.getLaunchYear(), edition.getLaunchMonth());
            //updateText(editionNameView, null, edition.getName());
            if(edition.getTotalCards() != 0) {
                updateText(editionSizeView, currentActivity.getString(R.string.total_cards), String.valueOf(edition.getTotalCards()));
            }
            updateText(cardsComposition, edition);
            String extraProperties = buildExtraPropertiesString();
            if(extraProperties != null && !extraProperties.equals("")){
                updateText(otherAttributes, currentActivity.getString(R.string.other_attributes_label), extraProperties);
            }
            if(edition.getImage() == null) {
                editionImageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_block_black_48dp);
            } else {
                if(!useAppStorage){
                    imagePath = SYMBOL_FOLDER + edition.getImage();
                } else {
                    imagePath = getActivity().getFilesDir() + "/" + SYMBOL_FOLDER + edition.getImage();
                }
                Drawable symbolDrawable = ImageUtils.loadImage(imagePath, getActivity().getAssets(), getResources(), SCALE_SIZE, useAppStorage);
                if(symbolDrawable != null){
                    editionImageView.setImageDrawable(symbolDrawable);
                } else {
                    editionImageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_block_black_48dp);
                }
            }
            editionNameView.setText(edition.getName());
        }
    }
```

**Third update**

This is very odd, i tried to use directly the string as it is, recreate a new textview from scratch, and for some reason this is the only one TextView that is not being updated.

There should be a reason.

And another odd thing, is that even if i try to set to it a costant string it doesn't display it.

Comment: Is your `edition` variable available from savedInstanceState each time? The fact that when you rotate the device causes the text to appear suggests to me that whatever value you want is not being passed in correctly

Comment: Yes, since all other field are filled correctly (and they are all from edition), the only one field that for some reason fail to display is the edition name. I tried to print edition.getName before setting it, and it is returning the correct name. But i'll post another update (Check in couple of seconds).

Comment: because i'm on a fragment?

Comment: ah and apparently the problem is with the layout, not the code! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this is what i think was the problem
In order to fix it i have to delete the item, and change the id of the item.

But digging in other layouts, probably the problem was that since i was using findViewById from the activity instead of the view, there was another item called edition_name in another view, so i suppose that the activity returned that reference instead of the one related to the current view.

I used the activity, since in my code i needed to access other components, not only related to the view, so i assumed to avoid to sue two different object to use only one to access everything.